# How to set up a zend modular application

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

im trying to set up a zend modular application my actual directory structures is like :

```
\Application
\Application\modules
\Application\modules\admin
\Application\modules\admin\...
\Application\modules\admin\Bootstrap.php
\Application\modules\front
\Application\modules\front\...
\Application\modules\front\Bootstrap.php
\...
```

And my application.ini file contains :

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/front/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Front_Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"

resources.modules[] =
resources.view[] =

;FrontController Resource Settings
;resources.frontcontroller.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/front/controllers"
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "front"
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1


resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "test"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"

;resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/front/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"


[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

when i'm trying to access http://mywebserver/appname/public/ i get this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'No default controller directory registered with front controller' in C:\wamp\www\go\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php on line 91
```

anyone can help plz !
thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **uncomment** your `resources.frontcontroller.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH`"/modules/front/controllers"
and try changing:

```
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
```

to:

```
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
```

as the documented parameter is [defaultControllerName](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the problem was the bootsrap it self :
ive puted 1 bootstrap file per module ... when i deleted them and left only the main bootsrap file it works fine.
thanx for your answer.

Comment: you should have one bootstrap per module but the module bootstraps should extend `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`. These module level bootstrap files facilitate things like autoloading and routing. Without a module bootstrap you may encounter issues with your modules autoloading and routing to certain files/pages.